# *Highchart* Hide legend but the values should be kept as before

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a stacked column bar with stacking as percent:

```
`stacking: 'percent'
```

[My code's fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/0qwcLeuh/1/)

and when I click to the legend to hide them, the values of the bar will be changed. What I expected is the values should be kept as they were before, only the chosen bars are hide. For example for the 1st column, the Apples: we have John 50%, Jane 20% and Joe 30%. If I hide John, then Jane will get 40% and Joe will have 60% which are not corrected to the given data at the beginning. How can I still kept Jane and Joe data even when I hide John ?

Comment: You can check this example http://jsfiddle.net/kanz3/1/

Comment: @User555 thanks for your solution, it seems correct when I hide series 1 first, but if I hide series 2 first then unhide, then the series will overlap the x-axis label, and what I wish to have is when I hide series 2, the series 1 should be falling down to stay at the xaxis, not locate at the between of the graph

Comment: Stacking charts use all series visible to determine, in this case, percentage. If you remove a series from being visible, then you have modified the components used to make the percentage of the whoel. If you don't want percent stacking but instead numeric stacking (`stacking: 'normal'`). Basically you cant have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: hi wergeld, it means that not possible in percent chart to make one series invisible but still kept the other series's values, is it right ?

Comment: Correct. Out of the box this is how highcharts calculates percentages. You can create your own data that is percentages already and add to chart.